# How can I destroy a clone of a Prefab in Unity 3D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make it so that a projectile, (in my case a slice of pizza) is destroyed once it travels a certain distance. I have no errors in my code and I don't know what I'm doing wrong, please help I'm fairly new to coding in Unity. (I have a comment written in the spot I need help with)

Here's my script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float horizontalInput;
    private float speed = 12.0f;
    private float leftBoundary = -10.0f;
    private float rightBoundary = 10.0f;

    public GameObject pizzaPrefab;
    private GameObject pizza;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

        transform.Translate(Vector3.right * Time.deltaTime * speed * horizontalInput);

        if (transform.position.x < leftBoundary)
        {
            transform.position = new Vector3(leftBoundary, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
        }

        if (transform.position.x > rightBoundary)
        {
            transform.position = new Vector3(rightBoundary, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
        }

        // This is the part i need help on!!!
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            pizza = Instantiate(pizzaPrefab, transform.position, pizzaPrefab.transform.rotation) as GameObject;

            if (pizza.transform.position.z > 35)
            {
                Destroy(pizza);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your check for destroying "pizza" is INSIDE the check for the spacebar, meaning that it'll only attempt to destroy "pizza" `if (y > 30 AND spacebar pressed)`

Move your "pizza" destruction check to be OUTSIDE the spacebar if statement.

*(Preferably, the Pizza object should have it's own MonoBehaviour checking it's position, rather than relying on the object that shot it, but I digress.)*

```cs
//beginning of Update()

if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
{
    pizza = Instantiate(pizzaPrefab, transform.position, pizzaPrefab.transform.rotation) as GameObject;
}

if (pizza.transform.position.z > 35)
{
    Destroy(pizza);
}

//end of Update()
```

Comment: When you have a script attached to a GameObject you can just write 'transform.Translate(x,y,z);' You don't need to reference a GameObject beforehand, "private GameObject name;" So if I give the pizza object it's own script to check when to be destroyed how can I tell it to destroy itself? When the Destroy() Method asks for those references (Also thanks for the answer it was just dumb mistake now that I see it)

Comment: @That one bad coder It's as simple as doing `Destroy(gameObject)`, where `gameObject` is a member variable of the MonoBehaviour class. It refers to the game object that the script is attached to.